# Understanding how fork() system call works

Tags: c, unix, process, fork, pid

I have this C code sequence:

```
    printf("\nThe PID of this (main) process is: %d\n", getpid());

    if(fork() != -1) { // #1
        printf("\n\nParent 1 PID: %d\n", getpid());
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            printf("\n%d", i);
        }

        if(fork() != -1) { // #2
            //sleep(1);
            printf("\n\nParent 2 PID: %d\n", getpid());
            for(char i = 'a'; i != 'f'; i++) {
                printf("\n%c", i);
            }
        }
        else { // #3
            sleep(3);
            printf("\n\nChild 2 PID: %d\n", getpid());
            for(char i = 'F'; i != 'J'; i++) {
                printf("\n%c", i);
            }
        }
    }
    else { // #4
        sleep(4);
        printf("\n\nChild 1 PID: %d\n", getpid());
        for(int i = 10; i < 20; i++) {
            printf("\n%d", i);
        }
    }
```

I expect that I will have 4 processes: two parents and two childs.
At line #1 I call `fork()` for first time, and everything from line #1 to line #4 will be executed in first parent process.
In the parent process (1) I call `fork()` one more time, so from line #2 to line #3 I will have the parent 2 process, and from line #3 to #4 child 2 process.

What I expect to be printed:

```
Parent 1 PID: ....
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Parent 2 PID: ....
a
b
c
d
e
Child 2 PID: ....
F
G
H
I
Child 1 PID: ....
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```

What I actually got:

```
Parent 1 PID: 3877

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8


Parent 1 PID: 3878

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Parent 2 PID: 3877

a
b
c
d
e9

Parent 2 PID: 3878
9


a
b
c
d
Parent 2 PID: 3879

a
b
c
d
e9

eParent 2 PID: 3880

a
b
c
d
e
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: What does `fork() != -1` check for?

Comment: If the call fails, -1 will be returned. So I check if the call didn't fail.

Comment: So what do the `else` blocks do?

Comment: The `e9`s are due to the backwards `printf`s. Putting the `\n` at the end of the `printf`s will fix that.

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth Well, now I see the problem:
If the call fails, `if` statements become false, and then `else` statements will be executed.

Comment: @MariusMG: That's part of it. Remember that a successful `fork()` call will return *twice* -- once in the child and once in parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line isn't doing what you think:

```
if(fork() != -1) { // #1
```

That will succeed for both the parent and the child (as long as `fork` is possible, which is almost always the case). You mean to test against 0 here. The parent will get 0, the child will get >0. -1 is an error.

In your case, what you've marked as the "child" legs should never be executed unless there are errors. I don't think that's what you meant. What you're seeing are the initial 2 (parent and child) forks plus 4 (parent+child * 2) second forks. That's 6 forks, which is what the output indicates.

Answer (score 2):

From `man fork`:

```
RETURN VALUE
       On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in the parent, no child process is created, and errno
       is set appropriately.
```

This means, that you should expect 0 in the child process and the childs pid in the parent process, so your code should look something like this:

```
switch(pid = fork()) {
  case -1:  //error handling here
  case 0:   // child process code here
  default:  // parent process code here.
}
```

Comment: I love Christmas, but I won't marry it. ;v) A *merry* Christmas to you, though.

Comment: haha thanks :-D i am no a native speaker as you may have guessed ;)

Comment: came for the code and stayed for the free grammar lesson :) +1